# Argala stotram, shadanga nyasa

Tags: durga

I've been chanting durgasaptashati using a format widely prevalent in Kerala.  In the Argala stotram shadanga nyasa portion it is given as 'am gam lam ithyadi shadanga nyasa'(अं गं ळं  इत्यादि षडङ्ग न्यासः, അം ഗം ളം ഇത്യാദി ഷഡംഗ ന്യാസ : ).  It would be of great help if any body can provide the beeja manthras for this.  I am familiar with the nyasa mudras.  I only need  the beeja manthras.